# How to clean the caches for a taxonomy in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy-terms

Is there any way to clean the cashes for taxonomy in WordPress?

Answer (score 1):

I found it my self.

Yes, it is possible to clean the cashes for taxonomy in WordPress.

```
clean_taxonomy_cache( $taxonomy_id );
```

Please note that this was added in 4.9 and you can use this function only in WordPress 4.9+.

So if you are going to use this for a WordPress plugin, please use the following code.

It prevents breaking other versions of WordPress sites.

```
if (function_exists('clean_taxonomy_cache')) {
    clean_taxonomy_cache( $taxonomy_id )
}
```